# Parsing a JSON object from Google Books

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to generate a book list like this:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/books/examples/viewability-with-callback

from a JSON object using Google's API for Google Books.

I've only used JSON with YQL before, and I've parsed the results like this:

```
$.each(data.query.results.row, function (i, item) {
```

as I did here
http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/U2QWY/4/

but with Google Books, the JSON object contains unique ISBNs as objects, so I can't parse them the same way:

```
$.each(data.ProcessGBSBookInfo.[[uniqueisbn]], function (i, item) {
```

How can I do this? My fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5tWQh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your fiddle updated to work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/5tWQh/1/

I changed your url to allow for proper JSONP callback handling, and then modified the $.each to have it iterate through the returned isbn numbers.

```
$.getJSON('http://books.google.com/books?jscmd=viewapi&bibkeys=0596000278,00-invalid-isbn,ISBN0765304368,0439554934&callback=??', function(data) {
...
$.each(data, function(i, item) {...
```

Comment: bonus question: is there any way to feed the variables dynamically, so that instead of &bibkeys=0596000278 in the query it takes them from, maybe a Google Doc via YQL or something..

Comment: Google's API has this example where ISBNs are loaded from a form submission https://google-developers.appspot.com/books/examples/ajax-example I'm wondering if the ISBNs could be pulled from another source (via YQL or whatever) and used to generate a list like my fiddle.. may be a long shot..

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly, it wouldn't matter where you got the isbn numbers, whether it's a form submission or some external API accessed through YQL, you would just have to convert them to a list and place it into the getJSON url.

Comment: right, how do I place it in the getJSON url: can you do variables like &bibkeys={$isbns}&callback=?

Comment: Exactly like that. `"...&bibkeys=" + $isbns + "&callback=??"`